# incalculable convergent series

Tags: logic, convergence-divergence

can you define some sort of infinite procedure (algorithm) which approximates a rational number with infinite precision but whose limit cannot be calculated in a finite number of operations as is the case with any irrational number.
or in other words can there be an unknowable infinitely approachable rational number

Comment: I don't understand. Can you be more precise? It is trivial to compute any rational to arbitrary precision, so what you wrote is not really what you mean.

Comment: Are you asking if there are any "infinite expressions" for any rational numbers? Does it have to be a series?

Comment: i will try to be more precise.

Comment: on second thought my original phrasing is poor, since for example i could define a series  whose terms are 1 if the continuum hypothesis holds and 0 otherwise....what im looking for is a rational number that can be approximated with infinite precision but cannot be calculated in a finite number of steps as is the case with any irrational number(actually i presume this is impossible and would like to know why)

Comment: A number is rational if and only if it has an (eventually) repeating decimal expansion. For any such expansion, it is easy to write a computer program which on input $n$ returns the $n$th decimal place. I take it that is what you mean for something to be "calculated precisely in a finite number of steps". Of course, the trick here is I haven't told you which computer program to use; given the series, I can't tell you precisely what the program computing the limit is unless I also know this limit.

Answer (score 1):

Let be $a_n = 1/2^n$ if ZFC is consistent, $a_n = 0$ if ZFC is inconsistent. Then,
$$S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$
is rational (0 or 1). But:

If ZFC is consistent, we can't prove that $S = 0$ (obviously) nor $S = 1$ (why?)

If ZFC is inconsistent, we can prove that $S =$ anything,

Comment: i rephrased my original question in the comment above to account for such answers....thank you for the swift reply though